# textarea doesn't change in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I call `$("#editor1").val(data);` outside `jQuery.ajax` data shows up in the textfield of textarea. When I try to put it in the success function of jQuery.ajax nothing is displayed.

Can somebody answer why and how to change it in order to work?

Here is the code:

```
<script>
function getFromServer(id){
var data = {"id" : id};
jQuery.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost/amsprojektgit/amsprojekt/admin/web/ajaxg/"+id,
        method: "post",
        data: data,

        success: function(data) {
        $("#editor1").val(data);
        },

        error: function(){
          alert("Wystąpił nieoczekiwany problem!");
        }
      });


    }

</script>
```

This shows up on the contrary:

```
<script>
    function getFromServer(id){
      var data = {"id" : id};
    $("#editor1").val("Hi");

      jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/amsprojektgit/amsprojekt/admin/web/ajaxg/"+id,
        method: "post",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {

        },
        error: function(){
          alert("Wystąpił nieoczekiwany problem!");
        }
      });


    }


    </script>
```

Comment: Does you ajax fires correctly? What's `data` value?

Comment: Does this work online (i.e. not localhost)?

Comment: you can try **text()** instead of **val()**

Comment: post what this produces success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);  $("#editor1").val(data);
            }

Comment: When it won't work on `success`, this mean that the AJAX request wasn't successful. I'm sure that the answer is in your browser's devtools. Check network and console tabs. We're unable to provide more specific answer for such given question

Comment: The console output is fine. It shows up what is on the server side.

Comment: Did you already try @m.antkowicz's solution? If you're working with textareas, `.val()` won't work, since they don't have a `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I solved it. The problem might be that I am using CKeditor with textarea for text edition. The proper code should be:

```
function getFromServer(id){
var data = {"id" : id};
var a;

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/amsprojektgit/amsprojekt/admin/web/ajaxg/"+id,
    method: "get",
    success: function(response) {
    CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(response);


    },
    error: function(){
        alert("Wystąpił nieoczekiwany problem!");
    }
});
}
```

Thanx for your advice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  <script>
    function getFromServer(id){
    var data = {"id" : id};
    jQuery.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost/amsprojektgit/amsprojekt/admin/web/ajaxg/"+id,
            method: "post",
            data: data,
            success: function(responsedata) {
            $("#editor1").val(responsedata);
            },
            error: function(){
              alert("Wystąpił nieoczekiwany problem!");
            }
          });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: So you are worried that inside success callback `data` refers to `data` defined in the main function body, and using a different name would fix the problem? I don't think so. The cause should be something else.

Comment: This not a problem of data variable. I can also make $("#editor1").val("Hello"); The problem is that it doesn't show up when I put it in the sucess function. When I put it outside ajax call it shows up.

Comment: I agree that it is not the root cause. 
I tried with an example (http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/qqdspffu/1/). It is working fine.

Comment: Issue may be : 
1) Success function not called 
2) response data is null.
3) DOM element not rendered at the time of execution

Comment: 1) and 2) can be excluded. I tried alert(data); and it shows fine. So 3) may be a problem. Do you know how to make it work?

Comment: Try this code on success function alert($("#editor1").length). if it is one then the DOM exists.

Comment: This is one. What now?

Comment: That means the DOM element exists, what does your response data contain ?

Comment: The problem is not with response data. When I try to call   /*$("#editor1").val("Hi");*/" it doesn't show either. I think the problem might be the time of execution.

Comment: As most of the cases are analysed here , 4) Please check the scripts execution and the DOM element is in the same frames. 
5) try this code $("#editor1").attr('value', 'Hi');

My Final conclusion is to depend developer tools ,

Comment: "4) Please check the scripts execution and the DOM element is in the same frames. "
How to check it?

Comment: it is simple, are you using any iframes in you page ? and also did you checked the link i sent you ? http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/qqdspffu/1/

Comment: No I don't use any iframes.

Comment: Did you try 5 ?  If that is also not wokring please reproduce your issue in a http://jsfiddle.net and share me the link.

Comment: I also tried 5 but it doesn't work. Interesting is that $("body").append("Hi") works in ajax call. I can try jsfiddle but I never used it :(

Comment: jsfiddle is very simple to use see this documentation  :  http://doc.jsfiddle.net/tutorial.html